# NuSOAP PHP Web Service

Tags: php, web-services

I am using NuSOAP to try to consume a Web Service built in Java. I have this code so far:

```
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php'); 
$wsdl="http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldWS/sayHiService?WSDL";
$client=new nusoap_client($wsdl, 'wsdl');
$param='John';#array('name'=>'John'); 
echo $client->call('Hey', $param);
unset($client);
?>
```

but when the web page gets loaded I get a blank page nothing not even in the code and I really don't know why. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

although NuSOAP is a very common PHP SOAP library, it's main use in PHP4 applications I think. because PHP5 has a built-in SOAP extension that is faster (because it is a compiled extension). I also recommend using Zend Framework SOAP library. but I remember I wanted to use some web service (not written by me, implemented in Java) and none of these SOAP clients worked, but the NuSOAP. and I really could not figure out why.

anyway, here is the thing that I did to use that web service back then:

```
$soapClient = new nusoap_client($wsdlFile, 'wsdl', '', '', '', '');
$soapClient->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$soapClient->debug_flag = false;
$soapError = $soapClient->getError();
if (! empty($soapError)) {
    $errorMessage = 'Nusoap object creation failed: ' . $soapError;
    throw new Exception($errorMessage);
}
// calling verifyT method, using 2 parameters.
$tResult = $soapClient->call( 'verifyT', array($param1, $param2) );
$soapError = $soapClient->getError();
if (! empty($soapError)) {
    $errorMessage = 'SOAP method invocation (verifyT) failed: ' . $soapError;
    throw new Exception($errorMessage);
}
if ($soapClient->fault) {
    $fault = "{$soapClient->faultcode}: {$soapClient->faultdetail} ";
    // handle fault situation
}
```

Comment: Important point to note is you should disable the debug_flag in production. I've learnt it in a hardway.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use NuSoap. PHP has had a [native soap client](http://www.php.net/soap) since version 5, which is far more stable, besides being faster.

> .. when the web page gets loaded I get a blank page nothing not ..

That's probably a fatal error. Try checking the error logs to see what went wrong. Or set [`display_errors = on`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.errors.php)

Comment: I disagree. The inbuilt PHP SoapClient has issues and unresolved bugs.  Like this one >> http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48216&thanks=3 that prevents it from working at all.

Answer (score 4):

> Don't use NuSoap. PHP has had a native
>   soap client since version 5

There are some good reasons to keep using NuSOAP on PHP5 :

- NuSOAP generate a list of methods
  when you **GET** the page
- NuSOAP generate the WSDL "on the fly"
  a really useful feature that is not
  provided by native implementation of
  SOAP in PHP 5

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're doing something wrong. It's hard to know what based on a blank page, but I'd start with this line, which doesn't look like valid PHP:

$param='John';#array('name'=>'John');

"#" does not start a comment in PHP; "//" does

If fixing that still results in a blank page, turn on error reporting and/or add more output throughout to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: '#' also begins a line comment in PHP. It's just not used very often.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the HTML generated by the server in your browser.  In my case, the result contained XML tags, so the browser could not properly display the information.

Answer (score 0):

I was just facing the same problem.

Using `include_once` instead of `require_once` resolved the blank page problem. This is not the perfect solution of course, because of this: [Difference between require, include and require_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include)