# Difference between require, include, require_once and include_once?

Tags: php, include, require, require-once

In PHP:

- When should I use `require` vs. `include`?
- When should I use `require_once` vs. `include_once`?

Comment: PHP CodeSniffer says, if file is being included conditionally, use include_once (instead of require_once).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3633905/1045444

Answer (score 1656, accepted):

There are `require` and `include_once` as well.

So your question should be...

1. When should I use `require` vs. `include`?
2. When should I use `require_once` vs. `require`

The answer to 1 is described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp).

> The require() function is identical to include(), except that it handles errors differently. If an error occurs, the include() function generates a warning, but the script will continue execution. The require() generates a fatal error, and the script will stop.

The answer to 2 can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).

> The require_once() statement is identical to require() except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.

Note that nowadays there is little use for *_once variants. If you are using them, it's likely either a mindless habit or your code needs to be restructured.

Comment: Is the check for whether the file is already loaded done separately for each running instance of the script? For example, if multiple users are accessing your script from multiple computers, will the check for require happen once for every user? Last, is there an alternative way that PHP handles multiple concurrent uses of the same script?

Comment: @JoachimRives All the relevant PHP code is loaded every time a page is requested. So basically if 100 users load the "script" from different computers, the script will be included 100 times, of course, because every "session" is indipendent.

Comment: It's so awesome when answers include actual references. Shouldn't it be required? Thank you very much ✨

Comment: What's the rationale for "there is little use for *_once variants"? Seems to me the opposite should be true, at least if the files contain business logic rather than UI.

Comment: @LionelRowe can you think of a situation when you would include the same file twice? In only can happen if your code is a total mess. And in this case you'd better reorganize it, than using such a patch in the form of _once. Not to mention in the modern PHP you hardly include manually at all, thanks to autoloading (which is one of situations when _once is justified but that's another story)

Comment: @YourCommonSense "can you think of a situation when you would include the same file twice?" Yes, that's extremely common. E.g. say your CMS has a module for converting titles like "Title of the Page" into slugs like "title-of-page". You'll surely want to include that module in multiple places (generating permalinks before saving a new page to the DB, preview links for in-progress pages, etc), while only loading it once. I'm not primarily a PHP developer so maybe I'm just ignorant of PHP's quirks, but the concept of writing modular, reusable code is surely a best practice in every language.

Comment: @LionelRowe I see. That's where you are using the [autoload feature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) (most of time [handled by Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md)) which does all the include job. Like I said above, nowadays you scarcely has to include a file manually, least include the same file in multiple places. Using require_once has nothing to do with  modular, reusable code. Rather the opposite - trying to include the same dependency more than once means spaghetti code.

Answer (score 453):

Use

- [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)
  when the file is *required* by your application, e.g. an important message template or a file containing configuration variables without which the app would break.
- [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)
  when the file contains content that would produce an error on subsequent inclusion, e.g. 
  `function important() { /* important code */}` is definitely needed in your application but since functions cannot be redeclared should not be included again.
- [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
  when the file is not required and application flow should continue when not found, e.g.
  great for templates referencing variables from the current scope or something
- [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)
  optional dependencies that would produce errors on subsequent loading or maybe remote file inclusion that you do not want to happen twice due to the HTTP overhead

But basically, it's up to you when to use which.

Comment: Thanks for putting the information in the actual answer and not making me click more links to find it.

Answer (score 320):

My suggestion is to just use `require_once` 99.9% of the time.

Using `require` or `include` instead implies that your code is not reusable elsewhere, i.e. that the scripts you're pulling in actually **execute** code instead of making *available* a class or some function libraries.

If you are require/including code that executes on the spot, that's procedural code, and you need to **get to know a new paradigm**.  Like object oriented programming, function-based programming, or functional programming.

If you're already doing OO or functional programming, using `include_once` is mostly going to be *delaying* where in the stack you find bugs/errors.  Do you want to know that the function `do_cool_stuff()` is not available when you go to call for it later, or **the moment that you expect it to be available** by requiring the library?  Generally, it's best to know immediately if something you need and expect isn't available, so just use `require_once`.

Alternatively, in modern OOP, just [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) your classes upon use.

Comment: In the modern PHP 99.9% of the time you don't need _once, so it became just require.

Answer (score 43):

Difference between _once functions and without _once functions:
without _once code will be included again whereas with _once functions PHP keeps track of the included files and will include it only once.

Difference between require and include:
If a required file is not found PHP will emit a fatal error whereas for include only a warning will be emitted.

Answer (score 39):

`include()` will throw a warning if it can't include the file, but the rest of the script will run.

`require()` will throw an `E_COMPILE_ERROR` and halt the script if it can't include the file.

The `include_once()` and `require_once()` functions will not include the file a second time if it has already been included.

See the following documentation pages:

- [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
- [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)
- [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)
- [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Answer (score 33):

You should keep class and function definitions organized in files.

Use `require_once()` to load ***dependencies*** (classes, functions, constants).

Use `require()` to load ***template-like files***.

Use `include_once()` to load ***optional dependencies*** (classes, functions, constants).

Use `include()` to load ***optional template-like files***.

Answer (score 29):

### An answer after 7 years for 2018

This question was asked seven years ago, and none of the answers provided practical help for the question. In modern PHP programming, you mainly use `require_once` only once to include your autoloader class (composer autoloader often), and it will load all of your classes and functions (functions files need to be explicitly added to the `composer.json` file to be available in all other files). If your class is not loadable from autoloader you use `require_once` to load it.

There are some occasions that we need to use `require`. For example, if you have a really big array definition and you don't want to add this to your class definition source code you can:

```
 <?php
// arry.php
return ['x'=>'y'];

 <?php
//main.php
$arr= require 'arry.php'
```

If the file that you intend to include contains something executable or declares some variables, you almost always need to use `require`, because if you use `require_once` apart from the first place your code will not be executed and/or your variables will not initiate silently, causing bugs that are absolutely hard to pinpoint.

There is no practical use case for `include` and `include_once` really.

Answer (score 26):

Whenever you are using `require_once()` can be use in a file to include another file when you need the called file only a single time in the current file. 
Here in the example I have an test1.php.

```
<?php  
echo "today is:".date("Y-m-d");  
?>
```

and in another file that I have named test2.php

```
<?php  
require_once('test1.php');  
require_once('test1.php');  
?>
```

as you are watching the m requiring the the test1 file twice but the file will include the test1 once and for calling at the second time this will be ignored.  And without halting will display the output a single time.

Whenever you are using 'include_once()` can be used in a file to include another file when you need the called file more than once in the current file. 
Here in the example I have a file named test3.php.

```
<?php  
echo "today is:".date("Y-m-d");  
?>
```

And in another file that I have named test4.php

```
<?php  
include_once('test3.php');  
include_once('test3.php');  
?>
```

as you are watching the m including the test3 file will include the file a single time but halt the further execution.

Answer (score 21):

Use "include" for reusable [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) templates. Use "require" for required libraries.

"*_once" is nice, because it checks whether the file is already loaded or not, but it only makes sense for me in "require_once".

Answer (score 16):

The difference is in the error the commands generate. With `require`, the file you want to use is really required and thus generates an `E_ERROR` if it is not found.

> `require()` is identical to `include()`  except upon failure it will also produce a fatal `E_ERROR`  level error.

`include` only generates an `E_WARNING` error if it fails which is more or less silent.

So use it if the file is required to make the remaining code work and you want the script to fail the file is not available.

---

For `*_once()`:

> `include_once()` may be used in cases where the same file might be included and evaluated more than once during a particular execution of a script, so in this case it may help avoid problems such as function redefinitions, variable value reassignments, etc.

Same applies to `require_once()` of course.

---

Reference: [`require()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), [`include_once()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

Answer (score 10):

1. When should one use `require` or `include`?

   The `require` and `include` functions do the same task, i.e. includes and evaluates the specified file, but the difference is `require` will cause a fatal error when the specified file location is invalid or for any error whereas `include` will generate a warning and continue the code execution.

   So you may use the `require` function in the case where the file you are trying to include is the **heart of the system** and may cause a huge impact on rest of the code and you can use the `include` function when the file you are trying to include is a simple file containing some less important code.

   And my personal recommendation (for less important code) is to go for the `require` function everywhere in your code while it is in development phase such that you can debug code and later on replace all `require` functions by `include` function before moving it to production such that if you miss any bugs it will not affect the end user and the rest of the code executes properly...
2. When should one use `require_once` or `require`?

   The basic difference between `require` and `require_once` is `require_once` will check whether the file is already included or not if it is already included then it won't include the file whereas the `require` function will include the file irrespective of whether file is already included or not.

   So in cases where you want to include some piece of code again and again use the `require` function whereas if you want to include some code only once in your code, use `require_once`.

Answer (score 10):

1 - "require" and "require_once"  throw a fatal error if the file is not
existing  and stop the script execution

2 - "include" and "include_once" throw a warning and the execution
continues

3 - "require_once" and "include_once" as their names suggests ,
they will not include the file if the file was already included with
"require", "require_once", "include" or "include_once"

Answer (score 9):

With require the file must exist, if it doesn't then an error will display; whereas with include - if the file doesn't exist then then the page will continue loading.

Answer (score 8):

Require critical parts, like authorization and include all others.

Multiple includes are just very bad design and must be avoided at all. So, *_once doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 7):

[Include](http://php.net/include) / [Require](http://php.net/require) you can include the same file more than once also:

> require() is identical to include() except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will halt the script whereas include() only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which allows the script to continue.

[require_once](http://php.net/require_once) / [include_once](http://php.net/include_once)

> is identical to include/require except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.

Answer (score 7):

I was using function as below:

```
function doSomething() {
    require_once(xyz.php);
    ....
}
```

There were constant values declared in xyz.php.

I have to call this doSomething() function from another PHP script file.

But I observed behavior while calling this function in a loop, for first iteration doSomething() was getting constant values within `xyz.php`, but later every iteration `doSomething()` was not able to get the constant values declared in `xyz.php`.

I solved my problem by switching from `require_once()` to `include()`, updated `doSomething()` code is as below:

```
function doSomething() {
    include(xyz.php);
    ....
}
```

Now every iteration call to `doSomething()` gets the constant values defined in `xyz.php`.

Answer (score 5):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/require):

> `require()` is identical to `include()` except upon failure it will also produce a fatal `E_COMPILE_ERROR` level error. In other words, it will halt the script whereas `include()` only emits a warning (`E_WARNING`) which allows the script to continue.

The same is true for the `_once()` variants.

Answer (score 5):

`include()` will generate a warning when it doesn't find a file, but `require_once()` will generate a fatal error.

Another thing is if file is included before. Then `require_once()` will not include it again.

Answer (score 4):

In the age of `PSR-0 / PSR-4` autoloaders, it may be completely unnecessary to use any of the statements if all you need is to make some functions / classes available to your code (of course, you still need to `require_once` autoloader itself in your bootstrap file and `include` templates if you still use PHP as a template engine).

Answer (score 1):

1. Use **require** function when you need to load any class, function, or dependency.
2. Use **include** function when you want to load template-styled file

If you are still confused, just use **require_once** for all time.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you require a wrong path, PHP throws a fatal error and the shutdown function is called, but when you include a wrong path, PHP will continue execution, but it will just display a warning that the file does not exist.

From the English word *require*, PHP is told that the execution of the page or file depends on the file required.

From my experience, it's norm to require important files such as configuration files, database classes and other important utilities.

Answer (score 1):

They are all ways of including files.

Require means it needs it. Require_once means it will need it but only requires it once. Include means it will include a file but it doesn’t need it to continue.

Examples:

```
Require 'filename'
Require_once 'filename'
Include 'filename'
```

There is also an include_once function which includes a file once.

```
Include_once 'filename'
```

Don’t use capital letters where I have as I am typing from my phone.

Answer (score 1):

one thing I noticed, when using include I can only access the included files functions from the file that included it. With require_once, I can run that function in a second required_once file.

also: I recommend adding

```
if(file_exists($RequiredFile)){
    require_once($RequiredFile);
}else{
  die('Error: File Does Not Exist');
}
```

Because when require_once kills the page, it can sometimes echo the directory of your website files

Here's a custom function I made to require files:

```
function addFile($file, $type = 'php', $important=false){
    //site-content is a directory where I store all the files that I plan to require_once
    //the site-content directory has "deny from all" in its .htaccess file to block direct connections
    if($type && file_exists('site-content/'.$file.'.'.$type) && !is_dir('site-content/'.$file.'.'.$type)){
        //!is_dir checks that the file is not a folder
        require_once('site-content/'.$file.'.'.$type);
        return 'site-content/'.$file.'.'.$type;
    }else if(!$type && file_exists('site-content/'.$file) && !is_dir('site-content/'.$file)){
        //if you set "$type=false" you can add the file type (.php, .ect) to the end of the "$file" (useful for requiring files named after changing vars)
        require_once('site-content/'.$file);
        return 'site-content/'.$file;
    }else if($important){
        //if you set $important to true, the function will kill the page (which also prevents accidentally echoing the main directory path of the server)
        die('Server Error: Files Missing');
        return false;
    }else{
        //the function returns false if the file does not exist, so you can check if your functions were successfully added
        return false;
    }
}
```

usage example:

```
$success = addFile('functions/common');

if($success){
    commonFunction();
}else{
    fallbackFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`require` generate fatal error with stopping next line execution while file not found.

`include` generate warning but did not stop next line execution while file not found.

`require_once` do the same as `require` do but it will check if the file has already been loaded or not to be executed.

`include_once` do the same as `include` do but it will check if the file has already been loaded or not to be executed.

Note: `include_once` or `require_once` may be used in cases where the same file might be included and evaluated more than once during a particular execution of a script, so in this case it may help avoid problems such as function redefinitions, variable value reassignments, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, there are 4 similar functions for including and requiring files:

`include()`: The `include()` statement is used to include the contents of a file into another file. If the file being included cannot be found, a warning will be generated but the script will continue to execute.

`require()`: The `require()` statement is similar to include, but it generates a fatal error if the file cannot be found. The script will stop executing immediately.

`include_once()`: The `include_once()` statement is the same as include, but it will only include the file once, even if it is included multiple times in the same script.

`require_once()`: The `require_once()` statement is the same as require, but it will only include the file once, even if it is included multiple times in the same script.

In simple terms:

Use `include()` when you want to include a file and continue executing the script even if the file is missing.

Use `require()` when you need to include a file and stop executing the script if the file is missing.

Use `include_once()` or `require_once()` when you want to include a file only once to avoid any issues with duplicate functions or variables.

Note: In general, it is recommended to use `require_once()` over `include_once()` to ensure that the required file is included and not missing.

Answer (score 0):

It's often a matter of whether you want to load a client library conditionally, or go ahead and load it whether or not you're going to use it.

Here's concrete example; elaborating on what pcj said.

Say you have a configuration file storing your database username and password (conf.php):

```
<?php
//my site configuration file

//For Database
$location='localhost';
$dbuser='yourname';
$userpw='yourpassword';
$database='nameofdatabase';
?>
```

And a class with a static function that uses the database:

```
<?php
class UsedInLoop {
    public static function databaseQuery(){
        require(/path/to/conf.php);                //require_once will not work here
        $db = new mysqli($location, $dbuser, $userpw, $database);
        //yada yada yada
    }
}
?>
```

And that static function is used inside of another function that is being called iteratively inside a loop:

```
<?php
require_once('path/to/arbitraryObject.php');  //either will likely be OK at this level
$obj = new arbitraryObject();
foreach($array as $element){
    $obj->myFunction();
}
?>
```

You can only require/include the class once.  If you require/include it on every iteration of your loop, you'll get an error.  However, you have to include your conf file every time the static function is called.

```
<?php
class arbitraryObject {
    public function myFunction(){
        require_once(/path/to/UsedInLoop.php);   //This must be require_once. require() will not work
        UsedInLoop::databaseQuery();
    }
}
?>
```

Of course, moving it outside of the function could be a solution to that problem:

```
<?php
require(/path/to/UsedInLoop.php);   //now require() is fine   
class arbitraryObject {
    public function myFunction(){
        UsedInLoop::databaseQuery();
    }
}
?>
```

Unless you're concerned with the overhead of loading a class that might only be used in certain conditions and don't want to load it when it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

`require` has greater overhead than `include`, since it has to parse the file first. Replacing `requires` with `includes` is often a good optimization technique.

Comment: I know it's a late comment, but this is actually not true. `require` doesn't parse the file any more than `include` does. The `_once` versions of those functions each has a bit of overhead, but like others have said, it's close to negligible in most applications.

Answer (score -2):

Just use require and include.

Because think how to work with include_once or require_once.
That is looking for log data which save included or required PHP files.
So that is slower than include and require.

```
if (!defined(php)) {
    include 'php';
    define(php, 1);
}
```

Just using like this...