# What is the difference between include and require except warning and fatel error

Tags: php

What is the difference between include and require except warning and fatel error.

i have researched but coudnt found this answer right way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633900/difference-between-include-and-require-in-php

Comment: There isn't any difference other than the one that you've already identified

Comment: One of interviewer ask me to this question. I answered this but he is not satisfy this answer

Comment: Perhaps you should have explained ___why___ the two different behaviours, in what circumstances you'd use one or the other.... or perhaps asked the interviewer what he believed the differences were