# Can I define my classes separately if my classes are all in common.php

Tags: php, class, object

I would like to do the following:

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once "../includes/common.php";

$quoteShared = new quoteShared();

?>
```

common.php has:

```
<?php
require_once "../objects/quote/shared.php";
... plus many others
?>
```

This gives me the error of:

**Fatal error: Class 'quoteShared' not found**

I want to define classes separately to where I include them so I use the specific ones I need on different pages. Can it be done?

Comment: Yes.  It's a very common practice.  It seems that "quoteShared" is not found.  This is probably because it's not loading it from shared.php.  Double check your path.

Comment: Hmm OK seems fine but double checking now. What about "include" "require" and "require_once" - which should I use in example code block I posted?

Comment: I use `require` for classes that I load only once. If you are unsure, use `require_once`. Read the "[difference between require and include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633900/difference-between-include-and-require-in-php)".

Comment: It's better to just split all your classes in custom files and than do a autoload like given as answer below.

Comment: Always use `require_once`. Personally I like the naming strategy something like `require_once __DIR__.'/../include/foo/bar/baz.class.php';`

Answer (score 1):

That's a bad design strategy, you should take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: It's not a bad strategy as everyone can code however it suites them. But a loader system would be usefull, I agree.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure this is for me. A lot of my classes are named based on the folder structure they are in. We have multiple products, and each product has 3 types of class depending on which part of the system you are in. So I have a class called "myaccountFootball" which is in /class/myaccount/football.php - this is why I think auto loader would fail for me! Keeping a common.php will do...

Comment: Actually your class naming can help in writing a custom autoloader (or  several if you register them via spl). Anyway, if you're using php 5.3+ you can specify absolute path by using `__DIR__`, which represent the directory where your file is
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php