# PHPUnit Fatal error: require() when running test

Tags: php, xml, phpunit, bootstrapping

I'm new at PHPUnit and I'm having a problem when running the test.
I noticed that the problem was that I was not including the class I supposed to test so I put the following line:

```
require '../../files/Cliente.php';
```

But then it gaves me the next error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(../../files/Cliente.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/esperanza/Escritorio/clasificadosj-clasificados-7da0b31e6060/pruebas/files/ClienteTest.php on line 6

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../../files/Cliente.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/esperanza/Escritorio/clasificadosj-clasificados-7da0b31e6060/pruebas/files/ClienteTest.php on line 6
```

My directory structure is the next:

```
Project
    |_files
      |_Cliente.php
    |_Test
      |_ClienteTest.php
```

I don't know if I have to configure a XML document or a bootstrap first.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try `require '../files/Cliente.php';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you require a file that does not exists. As require will give a fatal error when a file is not found, you get that fatal error. Compare with: [Difference between "include" and "require" in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3633900/367456).

Check the path to the file you want to require and correct it:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../files/Cliente.php';
```

Make use of the [`__DIR__` magic constant](http://php.net/language.constants.predefined) so that it's easy to specify in a relative fashion to the php-file of the testcase you write while the path is absolute. You then prevent to use the [`include_path` configuration directive](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.include-path) which makes it easier to trouble-shoot.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what are the bootstrap and the configure XML for?

Comment: If it works it works. If it works then you don't need to configure an xml file or bootstrap.

Comment: Where do you see an URL?

Comment: @SebastiánUlloa: The bootstrap is normally to require all your classes for the testsuite (or an autoloader). As you do it manually you technically don't need a bootstrap but it's perhaps worth to look into it and establish an autoloader: http://php.net/language.oop5.autoload