# Difference between require and include in php

Tags: php

Today i have an interview and i am being asked by interviewer a question which is difference between require and include in php?
I answered him as the difference between require and include is if you require a file that can not be loaded then it gives the fatal error and script will not execute and on the ohter hand if you include a file that can not be loaded it only gives the warning and continuous to the execution of script.

He replied: what is basic difference between these two instead of warning and fatal error? i couldn't justify my answer there.

when i came back i google it but nothing i found except this. Anyone knows what actually he wants to ask or listen from me? or any other difference?

Comment: It sounds like your interviewer mislead you by asking you "instead of" the warning and fatal error - since those are [the only differences in the two functions.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) Had he asked what the difference was in addition to, perhaps you would have accurately responded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633900/difference-between-include-and-require-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) If we add a file with this method and it does not exists at the given path, a Fatal Error will occur.
***And the script will stop working ***

2) If we add a file with this method and it does not exist at the given path, a Warning will occur.
***And the script will not stop working ***

There are different types of errors in PHP.

But with `Parse Error` and `Fatal Error`, scripts stop working.

With `Parse Error` (Syntax error e.g. missing `;`), script will not run at all.

with `Fatal Error`, (e.g. including non-existing file with `require`, the script will execute till that line, but, not after that.)

Otherwise, they just show errors.

Comment: This is exactly which i answered to him but he said what is the basic difference ? i don't understand what he wants to listen form me?

Comment: @DDay I would've asked for a different interviewer - or just turned down the job.

Answer (score 0):

require will produce a fatal error (E_COMPILE_ERROR) and stop the script

include will only produce a warning (E_WARNING) and the script will continue

for more details check out this link

[Difference between “include” and “require” in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633900/difference-between-include-and-require-in-php)

[PHP File Inclusion](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_inclusion.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The `require()` function is identical to `include()`, except that it handles errors differently. If an error occurs, the `include()` function generates a warning, but the script will continue execution. The `require()` generates a fatal error, and the script will stop the execution.

A warning is a message saying **"You are doing something wrong and it is very likely to cause errors in the future, so please fix it."**

Answer (score -1):

What you answered is 100% correct. According to w3schools:

> The include and require statements are identical, except upon failure:
>
> - require will produce a fatal error (E_COMPILE_ERROR) and stop the script
> - include will only produce a warning (E_WARNING) and the script will continue