# Class 'Smalot\PdfParser\Parser' not found

Tags: php, pdf-parsing

I am trying to use [Pdfparser](http://www.pdfparser.org) library to parse a PDF file but I have some issues with classes inclusion.

I read the [documentation](http://www.pdfparser.org/documentation) but it doesn't works.

I use Windows and XAMPP.

- I created a directory in `/xampp/htdocs/pdf_import`
- I installed Composer and I've generated the `/vendor/autoload.php` in `pdfparser-master/src`
- I use the code example in documentation

Example:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Parse pdf file and build necessary objects.
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('document.pdf');

// Retrieve all pages from the pdf file.
$pages = $pdf->getPages();

// Loop over each page to extract text.
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    echo $page->getText();
}
```

When I run the php script I obtain this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Smalot\PdfParser\Parser' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf_import\pdfparser-master\src\import.php on line 8

Comment: Use `require` instead of `include`. - See as well [Difference between “include” and “require” in php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3633900/367456)

Comment: by using require I have not differences

Comment: But you have the certainty that the `vendor/autoload.php` file has been loaded. I merely suggested it for that reason not that you trouble-shoot at a wrong end.

Comment: So, to further progress on this: Which part of the error message do you have questions about? What actually is your question?

Comment: In which directory did you exectue the `composer update smalot/pdfparser` command from the docs?

Comment: I tried to execute composer update from pdfparser-master/ and from pdfparser-master/src (moving all files).
My question is why I have this errors. Probably is for this reason I cannot able to parse pdf file

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your path is not good for

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

*Verify if autoload is actually included.*

In **Codeigniter3/4** be sure you put the path in your config file

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

then in your controller/library

```
    // Parse pdf file and build necessary objects.
    $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
    $pdf    = $parser->parseFile(FCPATH . 'includes/temp/' . $pdf_file);
    
    return $pdf->getText();
```