# Cannot connect to local mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a database named `BetaPoints`. All of the credentials are located in a php file name `EstablishAccess.php` in the format of

```
<?php
  define (DB_USER, "BetaPoints");
  define (DB_PASSWORD, "password!");
  define (DB_DATABASE, "BetaPoints");
  define (DB_HOST, "hostname");
?>
```

I am trying to connect to the database with this

```
$connctn=mysql_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD)
or die("cannot connect to database");
mysql_selectdb('BetaPoints')
or die('cannot select database');
```

I am getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: DB_HOST in /home/content/06/8274306/html/beta/mysuperscript.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: DB_USER in /home/content/06/8274306/html/beta/mysuperscript.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: DB_PASSWORD in /home/content/06/8274306/html/beta/mysuperscript.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/06/8274306/html/beta/mysuperscript.php on line 6
> cannot connect to database

I have look for mistakes in my variables and I have logged in multiple times with the credentials that I have defined to those variables and I am still unable to find the mistake.

It says that I can not connect to local MySQL database when to my knowledge it is not a local database.

If any one has any suggestion post them below. I am trying to get help finding more information about what is going wrong and any solutions that I can do to make it work.

Comment: Pass an extra parameter to it `mysql_selectdb('BetaPoints', $connctn)` - Do use up-to-date APIs such as `mysqli_` or PDO. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. If you get a deprecation notice, then you'll know what to use instead.

Comment: I added error reporting to the document and I am using require ("EstablishAccess.php"); to have this variable i need to connect transfer into the php file and the error reporting said they were not defined. Should I be using i different function to do what I need it to do?

Comment: As per your edit, I did make an edit to my answer before you posted that. Reload it to see the changes I've made. But where is `mysqli_connect()` coming from? You cannot mix APIs like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Firstly, you are declaring [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), so there's no need for `$` variables syntax.

```
$connctn=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD)
```

So make sure that you're using the correct data for all your constants.

Also, your syntax for `mysql_selectdb('BetaPoints')` is incorrect.

It's missing an underscore between `select` and `db`.

Use either `mysql_select_db('BetaPoints')` or `mysql_select_db('BetaPoints', $connctn)`

- Consult, and as per: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Example as per the manual:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

However, `mysql_` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future releases.

Use `die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error())` instead of `or die('cannot select database')`

- Consider looking into [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

### As per your edit:

> *Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/06/8274306/html/beta/mysuperscript.php on line 6 cannot connect to database*

You're including and mixing `mysqli_` functions with `mysql_` somewhere that you have not told us how you're using those.

- **Those different APIs do NOT intermix with each other.**

Use one MySQL API only; not both.

Refer to the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Example from the `mysqli_connect()` manual:

```
<?php
//conection:
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mydb") 
or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

//consultation:

$query = "SELECT name FROM mytable" 
or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

//execute the query.

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

//display information:

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row["name"] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Would it be better to use the include() or require() function to import my variables? I think that is why its not connecting since some how my database variable are not being defined.

Comment: This Q&A on Stack will explain it better http://stackoverflow.com/q/3633900/ @user3600462

Comment: @user3600462 wait I noticed another error. I will edit my answer. Give me a minute or so.

Comment: @user3600462 Reload my answer. You are using constants, so there's no need for `$` signs.

Comment: I still get the connection error? Warning: mysql_selectdb() [function.mysql-selectdb]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/06/8274306/html/beta/mysuperscript.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_selectdb() [function.mysql-selectdb]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/content/06/8274306/html/beta/mysuperscript.php on line 8
cannot select database

Comment: @user3600462 I've made another edit, and reload it then read it in its entirety. You cannot mix `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions together. Use one, not both. That should get you started. Look under **As per your edit...**

Comment: I learned alot from this answer, thank you @fred-ii- for the ans, it solved my problem too, Vup for this great ans..

Comment: @student You're quite welcome. Glad to hear it has helped you also, *cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

You have defined constants and then called them as variables. That's the mistake. DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE, DB_HOST are constants and should be used like: DB_USER and not $DB_USER.

Also I recommend declaring them using quotes like this:

```
define ("DB_USER", "BetaPoints");
```

Then also, as another user commented first, mysql_selectdb syntax is wrong. The correct syntax is mysql_select_db ("db_name");