# Why is wp-blog-header is seperate from index?

Tags: php, wordpress

What it the advantages of having the code in `wp-blog-header.php` seperate from `index.php` in wordpress?

I tried to move the code in `wp-blog-header.php` to `index.php` and the website loads perfectly fine, I think.

Could someone please explain about the advantage of running a require function in `index` to call `wp-blog-header` instead to writing the `wp-blog-header` code in `index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code reuse. There is not only `index.php` as entry-script. Every entry-script that wan't to load Wordpress core library functionalities *and* templating functionalities can require that file.

Using require/include(_once) is the historic way in PHP to do code-reuse.

- [`include`](http://php.net/include) has/is often used for (HTML) tamplating code.
- [`require`](http://php.net/require) is more often used for PHP program code, like function and class definitions.

These are not rules set in stone, it's more what common usage patterns are. Both are very close to each other:

- [Difference between require, include and require_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include)
- [Difference between "include" and "require" in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633900/difference-between-include-and-require-in-php)

Comment: I am new to PHP and Wordpress. I tried to read about Code reuse online but the idea seem to be scattered. Would you be able to comprehend it for me

Comment: Let's say you've got two pages with the same header. You could write the same header two times or you could write the header once and re-use the code two times.