# What is the difference between include & require_once in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use require_once vs include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include)

I have been using both `include` & `require_once` many times in php , but still I'm not fully aware of exact difference between them.