# What is the purpose of using `include` in PHP?

Tags: php

What is the purpose of using `include` in PHP, because if the file does not exist then there is something wrong with either the script or the web servers configuration. Surely it is better to use `require` so that the problem gets highlighted.

So, what is the purpose of `include` in the language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use require_once vs include?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include)

Comment: @Michael I don't think so, plus that question doesn't make a lot of sense. Why would you compare `require_once`/`include` instead of `require_once`/`include_once`, `require_once`/`require`,  or `require`/`include` as is being done here?

Comment: @GGG The inconsistency & confusion in the title is addressed in the answers...

Comment: @Michael If this question really is a duplicate of that one, I'd think one of these questions would need to be edited to actually match the other. As far as I can tell, the questions are specifically asking for a comparison of different language features (but similar, and with some overlap, granted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something that is not *required* for the page to run *successfully*.

For example, think about a web page. You have a sidebar containing ads that is shared between pages. As a good developer, you stay DRY and put this in an *include* file. You wouldn't want the web page to *fail* (with fatal error) simply because the script couldn't find the file (say your co-worker uploaded it to the wrong spot). As such, you use `include` instead of `require`.

There are additional benefits - such as performance - to using `include`. But that's a real world example which should give you some perspective.

Comment: Still, the fact that it generates a warning indicates it's not really good practice. I always had the idea that `include` was in the language before `require`, but I'm having trouble finding evidence of this.

Comment: Jason - Please do not tell that to the bean counters and/or the advertisers!

Comment: **Ed** - True. All aspects of the page are equally important. **GGG** - I chose to address the *what is the purpose of `include`* part of your question. If you are curious about the history of PHP as a language, that's outside of scope (IMO).

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I am not the OP ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using require on a non-existant file, a fatal error will be raised, when using include - only a warning. That is the only difference.

These functions are only tools and how they will be used is up to the programmer.

Comment: But why is emitting a warning more useful than a fatal error?

Comment: also you should note require is slower then include

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it's useful when the file is not "required." ;)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It depends on how you suppress your warnings. Usually, no warnings are shown in production environment, so if including a missing file nothing wouldn't change, because warning would be suppressed, but if requiring - script would stop executing, because fatal error would be raised.

Comment: But why would you ever include a file that doesn't exist?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams usually you wouldn't, but if God-knows-what happens, and the file goes missing, wouldn't it be stupid, if script stopped working even if it could work fine without the file?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've run into this only once, where I was auto-generating code; in one particular corner case there was no code to generate, and the easiest way to code it was to use `include_once` in case there was no generated file to include. However, I ended up rewriting it as a manual check for file existence and a `require_once`, because I didn't like that it was generating warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Include simply takes all the content in a specified file.

Using include and require is the most asked question for new in php.

for what i understand require will throw a fatal error when file does not exist and include will throw a warning that state file is not been found or not exist.

This means using using those two have effect on users also. Throwing fatal error may cause panic on user (non-IT) while include may simple say its broken.