# When should I use include require and require_once in my examples?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use require_once vs include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include)

For example if I have:

```
header part(header.php)
footer part(footer.php)
list of functions (functions.php)
list of constants (constants.php)
connect to database part(connection.php)
footer part + close the connection part(footer.php)
```

In these example should I use `include`, `require` or `require_once` and please NOTE why?

Comment: What, `include_once` doesn't get no love?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For files that contain functions, classes and other utilities, you generally want `require_once` so that nothing is accidentally redeclared in multiple libraries (or something) and breaks stuff.

- `functions.php`
- `constants.php`
- `connection.php`

For files that are templates you usually want `require`, because they should be able to be included multiple times without causing issues. (Not that that's likely in the particular case of these two files.)

- `header.php`
- `footer.php`

You never* want to use `include` (or `include_once`). It's like `require`, but only shows a warning when the file doesn't exist - probably not what was intended.

Now you noted that your footer closes the database connection. You generally want to avoid side-effects in template files. Moreover, closing the database connection is probably unnecessary. (And given that you *can* close it, here's some advice: use PDO instead!)

Comment: Why redaclaring functions bad if that function is the same function?

Comment: @user1349313: 1. It would be pointless. 2. It causes an error.

Comment: yes I understand its pointless but how can it cause an error if the functionality of that function didnt change?

Comment: @user1349313: Because function redeclaration is illegal in PHP. How is PHP supposed to know that the function works the same?

Comment: what is PDO? sorry im a newbie

Comment: @user1349313: It's a better way of accessing databases in PHP. Reading material: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Answer (score 1):

Unless I specifically need to include a file more than once (say a template of something that is in more than one place on the page) I always use `require_once`.  Though in the case of a template, making that template a class which can have multiple instantiations would be a better pattern, and thus that file would only get included in once.  For example:

```
class TemplateExample() {
    function display() {
        echo "I'm a template!";
    }
}
```

and

```
$template = new TemplateExample();
$template->display();
echo "Some text between the templates.";
$template->display();
```

It's also worth noting that there are some sources out there that say not to use `require_once` or `include_once` because they are slower than `require` and `include`.  While it is true that they are slower, it is not noticable; it would take something on the order of 10,000 includes before your script was slowed by a millisecond.  This difference is so small that you should not worry about the speed.