# PHP : require/include unnecessary warning

Tags: php, include, require

Steps to regenerate the issue :

There are total 3 files

include.php contains :

```
<?php
    $var1 = 5 + $var1;
?>
```

require.php contains :

```
<?php
    $var2 = 5 + $var2;
?>
```

incvsreq.php will contain :

```
<?php
$var1 = 0; // Starting with 0

include('include.php'); // Includes the file so Adding 5 + 0

echo $var1.'<br/>'; // Result 5

include_once('include.php'); // Will not include as it is already included

echo $var1.'<br/>'; // Display again 5, as it was not included above

include('include.php'); // This will include again so 5 + 5

echo $var1; // Result 10

rename('include.php', '_include.php'); // Rename the file

include('include.php'); // Warning should occur on this line as the file is not present now, but the script should continue.

$var2 = 0; // Starting with 0

require('require.php'); // Includes the file so Adding 5 + 0

echo $var2.'<br/>'; // Result 5

require_once('require.php'); // Will not include as it is already included

echo $var2.'<br/>'; // Display again 5, as it was not included above

require('require.php'); // This will include again so 5 + 5

echo $var2; // Result 10

rename('require.php', '_require.php'); // Rename the file

require('require.php'); // ERROR should occur on this line as the file is not present now, and the script should not continue.

echo 'This is not displayed'; // This won't be displayed.
?>
```

Output of this script is :

```
5
5
﻿10
Warning: include(include.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\include\incvsreq.php on line 23

Warning: include(include.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\include\incvsreq.php on line 23

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'include.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\include\incvsreq.php on line 23
﻿5
5
﻿10
Warning: require(require.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\include\incvsreq.php on line 45

Warning: require(require.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\include\incvsreq.php on line 45

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'require.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\include\incvsreq.php on line 45
```

I understood the Fatal Error in the last and 3rd warning from the top but how did other warnings appear ? I am little confused here. I have commented each line for better understanding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use require\_once vs include?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include)

Comment: Well it is acting exactly as you have predicted what is the problem then? And why do you need such a thing? Use at least modular programming and introduce a function.

Comment: @zaf :  I know what is the difference between require and include. and when to use it. I am just not able to understand those warnings `include(include.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\include\incvsreq.php on line 23`.
@Ihsan : I am not scripting in such a way. These are just test files. I am trying to understand those warnings(1st, 2nd, 4th and 5th).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`understood the Fatal Error in the last and 3rd warning from the top but how did other warnings appear ? I am little confused here.`

If you look at the error log in detail. Error messages are being generated only on two lines as you expect. Line 23 and line 45. Even if they are showing 3 times, they are being generated only on those two lines for which you are asking. This code appears to be behaving like it should

Comment: Because php is checking different paths like default includes path etc

Answer (score 0):

Error line generate an MSG on few different levels of reporting and 
what get printed out is controlled by error_reporting level set in PHP
for more information check PHP Documentation... [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)