# php types of inclusion

Tags: php, include, require, require-once

I just read some articles about php's **require / require_once** respectively **include / include_once** and was just wondering when _once should be used?
Is it just the performace aspect or can I run into any difficulties when including / requiring the same file multiple times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about this scenario:

```
<?php

function a() {
}

?>
```

What's going to happen when you include/require it twice? "function a already declared".

Comment: Haven't thought about this. Thanks.