# What is difference between "include_once" and "require_once" in PHP?

Tags: php

What is difference between "include_once" and "require_once" in PHP?

```
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";

require_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
```

Is there any difference between these?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2418473/2510628

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Include will let the script keep running (with a warning) if the file is missing.

Require will crash if it's missing.

If you're using include for things which are 100% optional, then include will still work and require will explode.

If you include something that you think is optional, but some other piece of your script uses it, way down the line, then your script will explode there, and you'll probably have no idea why.

This is not a good way to write programs.

Otherwise, there isn't a difference between the two.

### edit

In typical usage, it shouldn't matter whether you choose to use `include` or `require`, 95% of the time.

As such, you should stick to `require` (or `require_once`), to tell you when you're missing a file you need.

The bugs that come from including files inside of included files, inside of included files, when one include up top is missing, are really hard to track down.

Some people prefer `include`, because they want to use that "feature".
Douglas Crockford is a JavaScript/Java/C++ guy, rather than PHP, but he suggests that features that look like bugs, or side effects which are indistinguishable from bugs, should be avoided for your sanity.

Mind you, if your entire project is completely class-based (or functional), and entirely modular, then you shouldn't have much use for include, aside from, say resetting values on a configuration-object at application initialization (including admin-override options or dev-debugging options) on an object that was already `require`d.

As you might guess, there are other ways of doing this.

And these are just suggestions, but suggestions that come from people who are smarter than I am, with decades of experience in dozens of languages.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - "What's the difference between `require_once()` and `include_once()`?".

Comment: So, What is the best way to Write Include or Require? @Norguard

Comment: @AmalMurali That is exactly the answer, in a human understandable format: `include` will continue execution with a warning, `require` will terminate with a fatal error, in the case the resource is missing. Perhaps you could read those first two statements again.  Also, he's not asking for the delta between `include` and `include_once`, so for the sake of this discussion, the *whole* difference between `include` and `require` applies to all instances thereof. Convention over configuration.

Comment: @FarwallGhost: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2418580/).

Comment: It doesnt answer the question..

Answer (score 22):

`include_once` will throw a **warning**, *but* will not stop PHP from executing the rest of the script.

`require_once` will throw an **error** *and* will stop PHP from executing the rest of the script.

Comment: good short explaination

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that [`require_once()`](http://php.net/require_once) will produce a Fatal Error on failure, while [`include_once()`](http://php.net/include_once) only produces a warning.

Answer (score 0):

page stop execute **require_once** can't be load required file and on the other hand **include_once** will continue instead of error in loading including file.