# PHP Code Sniffer explanation of rule PEAR.Files.IncludingFile.UseRequireOnce

Tags: php, phpcs

i'm trying to improve my coding style, so i'm starting to use PHP Code Sniffer to follow standards. Im confused by this rule "PEAR.Files.IncludingFile.UseRequireOnce" what's wrong on include_once? Is it serious violation of standard to suppres this sniff?

Thaks for your answers and advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "right" answer, it's whatever you want your coding standards to be.

Personally, I would use a rule that marked "require_once" as incorrect since it's the exact same as include_once with no chance to check the result for errors.  A fatal error because of class not found or a fatal error because require_once failed both have no chance for graceful recovery in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21814374/1348344):
[image]

So I prefer `require_once`, because I know when the file is missing. Also you can you use `file_exists()` if file loading is optional, to have it under control.

Comment: I think it depends on the situation. I prefer include, because it's not fatal. Anyway question was about violation of PEAR coding standard. As i believe now this rule is there because in perferct world everthing work perfect, so our require/include doesn't fail. When it does require force you to fix it more than include, it's more strict :-) :-)

Comment: My final note is not fatal either :). Having `file_exists()` warp around `require_once` in the code prevents such question as this, since knowledge is embodied in the code and not in the stackoverflow archives.

Btw, just wondering. Have you started using CodeSniffer and PHP-CS-Fixer?

Comment: Just CodeSniffer, it's part of Continuous integration (CI) procces, even for small project where phpcs is only one job in CI :-D Somehow fixer doesn't suit me, since it cant fix all errors and warning i produce :-D.

Comment: You're very good probably :D I use both, I'm very lazy: https://github.com/Symplify/EasyCodingStandard/blob/master/README.md#1-create-configuration