# How can I retrieve a php variable from cart.php on another php page? i.e amount

Tags: variables, cart

I have a mini cart in my template_header.php and I have a cart.php.  I am trying to retrieve product picture, product name and price in the mini cart. When I copy the bit of code from cart into the template_header.php, I am able to retrieve the above info but whenever I am looking at an item the product name and price of the privious item added to the cart is being displayed.

Is there any way I can retrieve a php variable in my template_header from my cart without copying any code because I think that will resolve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php):

```
/* cart.php */
function getStuff($all = true) {
   echo "Cart WAS HERE"; // Will echo to buffer;
   return [];
}

/* template_header.php */
ob_start(); // Start gathering any output to buffer;

require_once('cart.php');

$output = ob_get_contents(); // Get buffer content;
ob_end_clean(); // Erase any output in buffer;

$products = getStuff();

echo $output; // Will output "Cart WAS HERE";
```

[Difference between `include` and `require`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include)

Comment: Hello, when I try implement the code above the cart.php is being rendered above my template header and on all the pages.  Can you please elaborate on your example.  thanks you

Comment: @wazza Use `ob_*` functions. Updated my answer.