# MySqli object -> query not working in a specific php file

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a separate file with an instantiated `mysqli` object which is in the a folder called `includes` within the `root` called `connect.php`:

```
$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

if ($db -> connect_errno) {
    echo $db -> connect_error;
}
```

My first page has a `require` and uses the object `$db` to carry out a `real_escape_string` task which works well.  I have a `functions.php` in the `includes` folder also.  Within that there is a function called `sendToDB` that uses the `query` function.  The `functions.php` includes the the `require` function also.  However, I get message:

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object...

If I instantiate the object within the function `sendToDB` it successfully writes to the DB.  As soon as I take it out, I receive the same message.  Is this a global issue?  or am I best instantiating it everywhere I need it?  Also if using `$db` on multiple pages, is it safe to run `$db->close();` after finishing with it on each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of the functions that use the database object (e.g. sendToDB), make sure you've got the line :

```
global $db;
```

It is ususally required in order to use global variables inside functions.

Comment: Good stuff :-) works a treat.  I didn't think it about it being `global` due to it being `required`.  Is it best to have `required` or `required_once` like my `functions.php` file is within the other php pages.  Its just I read that php does not like functions being declared more than once.

Comment: Check that link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include

Basically, as soon as you've got functions in the file, you should perform a require_once. If it answered your question, please mark my answer as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks again - yes I tried to mark you correct instantly, but it told me I had to wait for a few mins.

Comment: Just another question if ok - I did mention it above.  Now I have everything working, is it okay or best practice to perform `$db -> close()` at the end of each page?  I have tried it and it seems to be ok so far.  The object must re-instantiate itself when it sees its needed if and when on each page?

Comment: Yes, performing a $db->close() at the very end of your script is the way to go!