# Can't include php class

Tags: php, path

This is my directory structure:

classes
 - myphpclass.php
controller
 - controller.php
index.php

Now, I want to include myphpclass.php in my controller, but I don't know how to path it.

I'm trying something like `include('classes/myphpclass.php');`

But I can't make it to work

Comment: Why dont you **include(dirname(__FILE__)."/C.PHP");** ?

Comment: I tried with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], is it the same thing ?

Comment: just echo **dirname(_FILE_)** to see if its the same thing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../classes/myphpclass.php'));
```

Better use require_once : [Difference between require, include, require_once and include_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include)

Answer (score 1):

Start all paths with a forward-slash - then they are all relative to the ROOT.

```
include('/classes/myphpclass.php');
```