# Should I use PHP include?

Tags: php, html, include, client, server

I am building a site and I have used a bunch of php includes to a lot of page sections to try keep my code tidy.

While reading a beginners book on Javascript it said that I should keep my external javascript files down to a minimum because every time the client loads a file it makes a new request to the server thus slowing down the page speed.

So my question is if I have a bunch of php include files on one page is it the same principle? It probably is right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP include Or require? and which file comes first and which right after?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387186/php-include-or-require-and-which-file-comes-first-and-which-right-after)

Comment: If you know the difference between `include` and `require` you will know where to use them.

Comment: "The include and require statements are identical, except upon failure:" – Thanks Shaiful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the same principle, javascript files are downloaded and interpreted by the client; which is why you want to keep their size and number low (since bandwidth is limited).

PHP files are *not* downloaded by the client; they are interpreted by the server where you upload them; their output will be send to the client. This is why the number of PHP files does not have a negative impact on your page in the same way as javascript does

Comment: Is it impact to SSD speed?