# Get page.php using php code

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working with wordpress.

I see that in my index.php there is a code called `<?php get_footer(); ?>` ..and I get it, it's simple. This code will pull `footer.php`.

It seems to me that the `get_footer()` is built in to wordpress that pulls anything that is named `footer.php`.

I have created my own page called `page.php`.

I want to be able to 'get' this page and show in my php code enabled 'sidebar widget'.

I have tried to paste this code, and I am more that certain that its wrong:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("side.php");
?>
```

What code would I need if I want my custom page called `page.php` to be shown?

Comment: try `include 'side.php';`

Comment: `<?php include('filename'); ?>` use this

Comment: On another note: `file_get_contents` will download the file's HTML contents as shown in a web browser. This is not what you want, you want to include or require your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WordPress way to load a template file is [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_template_part):

```
get_template_part( 'page' );
// loads page.php from the theme directory.
```

Note that `page.php` is a special filename in WordPress themes, this file is loaded as a template if a page is displayed. You should give your file a different name if you want to prevent this.

Details are in the already mentioned [template-hierarchy.png](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png)

**Edit:**

After rereading your question: If your `page.php` is not from a template, but in a folder of a plugin you are developing as a sidebar widget, the also already mentioned `include('page.php');` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

page.php is a special page of wordpress. See this diagram.
https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png.

The wordpress way is to create a own template.
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
include ('side.php');
```

OR

```
require ('side.php');
```

you may also use include_once / require_once

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your php page

```
<?php include_once('filename.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use require_once or include in php file like below.

```
require_once('side.php');
```

or

```
include ('side.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
  require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/page.php' );
```

if your page is in same level where is your parent page.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many options that you can chose:

You can use `get_template_part()`:

> [From the Docs](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-and-require-files-and-templates-in-wordpress--wp-26419): WordPress now offers a function, `get_template_part()`,
>   that is part of the native API and is used specifically for reusing
>   sections - or templates - of code (except for the header, footer, and
>   sidebar) through your theme.

Other solution is `require_once()` or `include_once()`.
But if i compare both function `include_once()` is faster than to `require_once()` for smaller application.

For better understanding about the `require` and `include` you can read this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include).