# What is the advantage of using a require statement instead of require_once?

Tags: php

In PHP, a `require` statement will include and evaluate the specified file.

```
require 'path/to/some/file.php';
```

A `require_once` statement does the same but will check if the file has already been included and, if so, not include it again.

```
require_once 'path/to/some/file.php';
```

The benefit of using `require_once` is very clear but what's the advantage of using a `require` statement instead of `require_once`?

Ref:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: For one thing you might want to require a file more than once? It depends on the scenario and what the required file contains / does.

Comment: only advantage of ``require`` is microspeed, i can't imagine where i would use ``require``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That clearly depends on the contents of the file you're requiring and whether it should only be included once or explicitly again and again every time you request it; think partial templates as an example for where you might load the same file multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

`require()` includes and evaluates a specific file, while require_once() does that only if it has not been included before (on the same page).

So, `require_once()` is recommended to use when you want to include a file where you have a lot of functions for example. This way you make sure you don't include the file more times and you will not get the "function re-declared" error.

Answer (score 0):

Some good info related to your question on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include).

Specifically on the advantage of using `require()` over `require_once()`: `require()` executes ever so slightly faster so it could be beneficial to use if you're sure there are no duplicate requirements