# Why does only one of these PHP variables enter the global scope?

Tags: php

I have PHP files a bit like this

```
public_html/environment.php
public_html/task.php
phpbin/actions.php
phpbin/library.php
```

environment.php is included by public_html/* before any other php files are included, phpbin/* assumes everything in environment.php is already available.

It defines these two globals

```
$g_foo = "...";
$g_bar = "...";
```

task.php includes this logic

```
function do_stuff ()
{
    require_once determine_required_file ();
    ...
}
```

In this case, `determine_required_file()` returns "/path/to/phpbin/actions.php"

actions.php in turn contains

```
require_once "/path/to/phpbin/library.php"
```

Finally, library.php contains

```
$x = $g_foo;
$y = $g_bar;
```

I get this error:

```
Undefined variable: $g_bar;
```

Now, `$g_foo` and `$g_bar` are *strictly read-only* except in environment.php, I have exhaustively grepped and verified that there are no other places which create or modify variables with these names.

I am aware that PHP globals are weird, and doing things like including files from within functions can mess up your scope. I know that I should probably use `define()` or some other method, yeah yeah.

My question is this (yes, I'm asking you to speculate in the absence of full code, sorry):

Why might `$g_bar` generate an error but not `$g_foo?`

I assume the in-function-inclusion is probably responsible, but *assuming these globals really are read-only*, what should I be looking for as the culprit for *why one ends up in global scope in library.php but not the other*?

Comment: Unless you explicitly use the `global` keyword, *neither* should be accessible inside a function (all your code is executing in a function context). As such, can't reproduce/can't advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `include_once` instead of `required_once` for your fields that needed your global variables, or define a `global $g_bar, $g_foo`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I use require because it fails hard if there is an error. If I switch to include, how can I make it fail hard in the same way?

Comment: Use `global $g_bar, $g_foo` when you use `required` or `include` in order to tell that those variables need to be used in your file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include. `include` will not failed on non-existing file, `required` does. http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php I thing `include` is better in your case because of variable scope