# Is there a way to stop `<script>' from loading the same javascript twice in PHP/Javascript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a PHP `require_once` or `include_once` for `<script>`? I know `<script>` is pure HTML, but does PHP or HTML have such a thing?

I would like to prevent javascript from loading twice in the same page.

Example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-0.4.ajaxify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This Would Help you.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-and-include-once

Comment: I asked this specifically about <script>, because I want this specific behavior but for javascripts.  It is so useful for php in case you load something twice, it will only load it once.

Comment: It is a javascript/html question, not a PHP question.

Comment: You are right, I have it listed as html and javascript.  I thought PHP might have a solution also for the a possible double loading issue.  I changed the question to be more inclusive of javascript and html.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way you can run script tags in php would be

```
<?php  
....Here is php code
 ?>
   ... add the  script here(<script>....</script>
 <?php
  ?>
```

Another probable way is :

Using php inside the script tags for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var alertMsg = '<?php echo $custom_message; ?>';  
   alert(alertMsg);
 </script>
```

If you are using buttons

```
echo('<button type="button" onclick="customfunction();">My Button</button>');

<script>
//call your customfunction here

</script>
```

AN UPDATE TO SOLVE LOADING SCRIPT CONTENTS TWICE

I would suggest use of javascript function which are called to the specific page as they are needed an example would be

Create a file with a .js eg

```
example.js
here declare your functions you would put in the script tags of a html page
```

In the page you want to use the `<script>`

```
Include the example.js file and you can call the custom functions from there use the obect orientend approach
```

Check [This resource for more info about obect orientend javascrip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: Let's say you load the same javascript twice.  This is why you would use require_once.  It will only load the php once instead of twice.  This is what my goal was for <script>.  Does javascript have this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for this:

http://wonko.com/post/painless_javascript_lazy_loading_with_lazyload

Comment: That's cool!  Too bad there isn't a built in javascript function.  We have 1000's of pages of code, so sometimes you aren't sure if something gets called twice. :)

Comment: "Note: LazyLoad is no longer being maintained." [Source](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/)