# requiring_once a page required before

Tags: php

i have 2 pages their heads are like this

header:

```
<?php require_once "database.php"; ?>
```

page:

```
<?php require_once "database.php"; 
//some codes; 
require_once "header.php"; ?>
```

I had to require database again for a script to collect data correctly for a specific page, Would that affect the page performance? Or the `_once` fixes that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between require, include and require\_once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-and-require-once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on PHP documentation if you had used `required_once` for a file then it will not be required again. If there is a cost on performance? **NO**.

> The require_once statement is identical to require except PHP will
>   check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include
>   (require) it again.

[require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php#function.require-once)

Comment: So there is no problem with what i did in the page?

Comment: @CaliburVictorious no that is the point of `require_once` it does a check. There is a link to the PHP documentation website. In addition even if there is a cost on performance (there is no such problem really) it would be either that or an error thrown in case of using `require`.