# PHP get file outside of document root

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, directory, document-root

here is my project structure:

Web root/document root:

```
/var/www/ all the website files in the the 'www' folder
```

I want to use `require` or `include` a file inside my folder OUTSIDE the web root/document root:

```
/var/extra-files
```

how can i get a file inside the `extra-files` folder using `require` or `include`?

```
require "OUTSIDE DOCUMENT ROOT/extra-files
```

thanks

Comment: use complete path to that file like `require_once '/var/extra-files/somefile.php'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure `apache` as permission to read the files on `/var/extra-files`, then you can use:

```
require "/var/extra-files/file.php";
```

---

You may want to read [Difference between require, include and require_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-and-require-once)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm wow... no way was it that easy. I just used this:

```
/var/extra-files/myfile.php
```

and it worked.