# PHP Fatal error: Class not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: php

I have a problem in PHP

> Fatal error: Class  not found in C:\xampp\htdocs.

In my sumber.php file theres a class Hope.

Please help me thanks

```
<?php 
   // include('cekSession.php');
?>

<div ui-content-for="title">
<span>Book APPT</span>
</div>

<div class="scrollable">
<div class="scrollable-content">
<div class="section">

<?php 
  $sumberData = new Hope();
  $ListDoctor = $sumberData->getListDoctor();

  print_r($a);
?>
```

Comment: include sumber.php.....

Comment: If this is not the same file that the class is defined in, you should use require_once to bring the definitions in that file into scope.

Comment: after i try include and require_once still error. i already put include and require_once in <?php require_once('sumber.php') ?>. still error :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to `include` or `require` the file which contains your `Class` definition.

Any of the following will be suitable, which one you use depends on whether you need to be notified if the file was / wasn't found.

See [This question and Answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-and-require-once)

```
<?php
    //include 'sumber.php';
    //require 'sumber.php';
    //include_once 'sumber.php';
    //require_once 'sumber.php';
```