# How to properly use PHP require

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, include, require

I have 3 files: `index.php`, `db.php` (database), and `functions.php`

here is an example what is in each file:

**database.php:**

```
define ("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define ("DB_USER", "root");
define ("DB_PASS", "1234");
define ("DB_NAME", "test");

try {
    $dsn = "mysql:dbname=".DB_NAME.";host=".DB_HOST;
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**index.php:**

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/db.php";
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/functions.php";

if(isLoggedIn()) {
    echo "hi";
}
```

**functions.php:**

```
function isLoggedIn() {
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/db.php";

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users....");
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

---

The error i get is:

> Notice: Constant DB_HOST already defined in /var/www/config/database.php

**what i tried:**

I tried to replace `require` with `require_once` in all my files but the error that it gives is here:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in functions.php

Comment: change all your `require` to `require_once`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between require, include and require\_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2418473/6521116)

Comment: Even better, remove the `require` from `functions.php` and pass `$dbh` to your `isLoggedIn` function as an argument

Comment: Also, your application will continue to run if PDO cannot connect to your DB. I suggest putting an `exit` in your `catch` block or removing the `try...catch` completely

Comment: @KrisRoofe sorry please look at my edit

Comment: @phil yes that solutions seems hacky tho... also, i will put exit thanks

Comment: @JohnJaoill in what way is [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) *"hacky"*?

Comment: As @Phil says, injection is a standard method to pass resources, I think what you have is fine (if it was reworked), but it is closer to "hacky" than injection is.

Comment: I see that require is actually not the problem here. The problem is in this line: `require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/db.php";`
It should be:
`require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/database.php";`

You have your file named database.php meanwhile you are trying to import db.php. Just correct that and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, since it didn't make a sense to you my last answer here is a full answer of what you can do to get rid of this problem once for all:

**db.php**

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; 
$user="root"; 
$password="1234"; 
$db="test"; 

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/db.php";

if(isLoggedIn($dbh)) {
    echo "hi";
}
```

**functions.php**

```
function isLoggedIn($dbh) {
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users....");
$stmt->execute(); 
}
function anotherfunction($dbh) {
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM others....");
$stmt->execute(); 
}
```

The above corrections will save you the pain of looking after the requires, you require the db.php once so that now you have access to its variable and pass as argument whenever needed.

Note: Thanks Phil for fruitful comments and good elaboration.

Comment: Please explain the down vote for knowledge purpose.

Comment: If you simply remove the `require`, you'll run into a scoping issue with the `$dbh` variable

Comment: I said well remove it from the index not the functions.php.

Comment: sorry that was a typo at first. also, if i remove the `require` from index.php, what if i have two functions in my `functions.php` file? there will be two `requires` which will conflict

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel my mistake

Comment: @Phil no problem man, thanks for elaborating, much appreciated.

Comment: please see my comment above, it still does not resolve the issue

Comment: Two functions? How can that cause an issue with requiring? You can simply require the     require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/db.php";
at the top of functions.php

Comment: Wait I'll write for you a full solution

Comment: yes i tried to require at the top of functions.php outside of all the functions and it says `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in functions.php`

Comment: I wrote you a full solution to your problem, I hope that helps.

Comment: i get the same error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in functions.php`

Comment: Your dbh is null, you have a problem while creating the PDO object. Are you sure of the db.php code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146590/discussion-between-john-jaoill-and-oussama-ben-ghorbel).