# PHPUnit - Procedural code needing to be included multiple times

Tags: php, phpunit, procedural

I am currently trying to build up a phpunit testsuite to test some ajax code which is written procedurally. **I am unable to edit the original code**, fooBar.php, because it might cause issues elsewhere. The issue occurs when I am trying to run a php file multiple times with different parameters; the code has a function which throws redeclare exceptions. Below is an example of what I am dealing with.

**fooBar.php - php file hit with an ajax call**

```
$foo = $_POST['bar'];

function randomFunctionName(){
    echo "randomFunctionName";
}

if($foo == "fooBar"){
     $jsonResponse = array('success'=>true);
}else{
     $jsonResponse = array('success'=>false);
}

echo json_encode($jsonResponse);
```

**fooBarTest.php - phpunit test file**

```
class fooBarTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{   

   private function _execute() {
       ob_start();
       require 'fooBar.php';
       return ob_get_clean();
   }    

   public function testFooBarSuccess(){
       $_POST['bar'] = "fooBar";

       $response = $this->_execute();
       $this->assertTrue((strpos($response, 'success') !== false) && (strpos($response, 'true') !== false));

   }        
   public function testFooBarFailure(){
       $_POST['bar'] = "notFooBar";

       $response = $this->_execute();
       $this->assertTrue((strpos($response, 'success') !== false) && (strpos($response, 'false') !== false));

   }
```

So when I run this test, I get the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare randomFunctionName() (previously declared in.......
```

The problem is coming from the fact that **fooBar.php** is technically already there when the second test, testFooBarFailure(), is ran. As you can see though, I need to rerun **fooBar.php** in order to get a new response.

Is there any way to remove **fooBar.php** from the php stack/memory so I can run it again as though it was never loaded from the first test? I have tried pulling the second test function into its own test class but when I run the testsuite as a whole, I get the same exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out a way to do what I was looking for. Long story short, I use CURL to hit the ajax file. This allows me to hit the file multiple times within my test without causing any re-declaration issues. Below is an example of my solution for the **fooBarTest.php** file.

```
class fooBarTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{   

   public function testFooBarSuccess(){
       $postData = array('bar'=>"fooBar");

       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); 

       $response = curl_exec($ch);      
       curl_close($ch);

       $this->assertTrue((strpos($response, 'success') !== false) && (strpos($response, 'true') !== false));

   }        
   public function testFooBarFailure(){
       $postData = array('bar'=>"notFooBar");

       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); 

       $response = curl_exec($ch);      
       curl_close($ch);

       $this->assertTrue((strpos($response, 'success') !== false) && (strpos($response, 'false') !== false));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has built-in function to checking that specific function is defined, it's called [`function_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php). Example:

```
if (false === function_exists('randomFunctionName')) {
    function randomFunctionName()
    {
        echo "randomFunctionName";
    }
}
```

Thanks to this, you can `include`/`require` file many times but function will be loaded once.

Second way is just import your `fooBar.php` once using `require_once` instead of `require` ([Difference between require, include and require_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-and-require-once)).

Comment: Neither of your suggestions will work. Checking if the function exists is altering the original fooBar.php. As I stated, I am not able to alter the original code. In the PHPUnit test file, I have to reload the file in order to send it new information. Requiring or including it once does not allow me to do that.