# Creating a separate php file for WooCommerce hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I can't seem to find any documentation on this so maybe someone here can help. I have been adding all my WooCommerce hooks to my functions.php file but I would rather have all of them in a separate file to keep things tidy. Obviously I will need another php file for these but how do I link it to the functions.php file so that the code runs as it does now? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create new file with your woocommerce hooks code name anything what u want.
Ex. `woocommercehook.php` and place file in theme folder.

in function.php file just include your `woocommercehook.php` file at last.

```
include("woocommercehook.php");
```

Done. all work same as early.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP include/include_once and require/require_once will work fine. However,
create another file with your hooks( `woo-hooks.php` ) and use WP get_template_directory to require the file.

```
require get_template_directory() . '/woo-hooks.php';
```

Comment: Why use require get_template_directory() . '/woo-hooks.php'; over include("woocommercehook.php"); ?

Comment: The require() function is identical to include(), except that it handles errors differently. If an error occurs, the include() function generates a warning, but the script will continue execution. The require() generates a fatal error, and the script will stop. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-and-require-once

require get_template_directory() - Returns an absolute server path (eg: /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/my_theme) ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory/