# Include multiple php scrips

Tags: php, include, require, declare

I´m using on my called page two php scripts (avatar.php and items.php). In **both** of the php datas i have another scripts included like that:

```
include "../site/api-oauth-master/Client.php"; // 
include "../site/api-oauth-master/GrantType/IGrantType.php"; 
include "../site/api-oauth-master/GrantType/AuthorizationCode.php";
```

I get now the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class OAuth2\Client, because the name is
>   already in use in /www/htdocs/xxxx/site/api-oauth-master/Client.php on
>   line 32

The line 32 of Client.php is:

```
class Client
{
    /**
     * Different AUTH method
     */
    const AUTH_TYPE_URI                 = 0;
    const AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION_BASIC = 1;
    const AUTH_TYPE_FORM                = 2;
```

Obviusly the problem comes because the Client.php script gets included two times. I thought with "include" this shouldn´t be a problem. Any tips how the scripts can inluded two times on the same page?

Comment: With include you somply take the content of a file and place it in the file where you included it. So you basically have two times declared the class Client -> Yourthought it would work with "include" are wrong. include is noething else than taking the content of a file and place it there where you included it. Like a copy paste. Try to replace `include()` by `require_once()` and it should work I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between require, include and require\_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-and-require-once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `include_once` or `require_once`.

`include_once "../site/api-oauth-master/Client.php"; //`

`include_once "../site/api-oauth-master/GrantType/IGrantType.php";`

`include_once"../site/api-oauth-master/GrantType/AuthorizationCode.php";`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: Please, edit your question by either adding links to docs, citing them or both and explaining why your solution works.

Comment: I tried it with require_once() and include_once and I still get the same error.

Comment: Now it works, sorry had some brackets after include_once. Thanks.