# PHP in another PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays in anther .php file, I want to access the array in another php, how do I go about it please?

LIKE:

**first.php**

```
<?php
$myarr = array(
array("text", "number")
);
?>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
echo $myarr[0][1];
?>
```

to get **number**.

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the include function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631265/using-the-include-function-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add :

```
include 'first.php';
```

at the beginning of your file second.php

Make sure you put the right path of your file first.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by many ways. *Some of them may not be appropriate for your scenario. So please choose better one for your requirement.*

> **1. Convert the array to string and pass the data using GET method.**

Implode or JSON is better. Then pass the string to another file via normal get method.

**first.php**

```
<?php
$myarr = array(
array("text", "number")
);
$jsonarr=json_encode($age);
?>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
$age=$_GET['age'];
$myarr=json_decode($age);
echo $myarr[0][1];
?>
```

> **2. Form submit**

If you wish, form POST can also be used.The array can be converted to JSON or string as described above.

> **3. Pass the array as COOKIE from one file to another.**

(Not recommended for large data)

**first.php**

```
<?php
$myarr = array(
array("text", "number")
);
setcookie("age", json_encode($myarr), time() + (3600), "/");
?>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
$age=$_COOKIE['age'];
$myarr=json_decode($age);
echo $myarr[0][1];
?>
```

> **4. Pass the array as SESSION from one file to another.**

(Not recommended for large data)

**first.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$myarr = array(
array("text", "number")
);
$_SESSION['age']=json_encode($myarr);
?>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$age=$_SESSION['age'];
$myarr=json_decode($age);
echo $myarr[0][1];
?>
```

> **5. PHP "include" function**

The first file contains only php and if there is no HTML or php echo or print, use include function to include the first file into the second file.

**second file**

```
<?php
include "first.php";
echo $myarr[0][1];
?>
```

> **6. file_get_contents**

(This will read a file into a string.)

**first.php**

```
<?php
$myarr = array(
array("text", "number")
);
echo json_encode($myarr);
?>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
$jsonarr = file_get_contents("test.txt");
$myarr=json_decode($jsonarr );
echo $myarr[0][1];
?>
```