# PHP include a class and use it in another included files

Tags: php, include

In my index.php file I have included my db_connect.php file.

If I include another file (page1.php) in index.php, can I call my `DB::query()` function in page1.php? I must include db_connect.php to page1.php too?

Comment: If you included page1.php after db_connect.php then yes

Comment: If you don't want to have page1.php dependent on index.php, you could also use require_once() in page1.php.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I try it without luck.I think it does not work because I load the page1.php with javascript...

Comment: ...what do you mean you load it with javascript?  page1.php won't know about index.php if you load page1.php in a separate request...

Comment: I do not have just one page and one class.

Comment: I load the page1.php in a div in index.php

Comment: @NoNameMan if you're loading page1.php inside index.php or you pass your db as a variable or you have to include it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: If you would share your code, we could better understand it. And if you had any problem, this might really be a good question.....

Comment: If you're loading page1.php with javascript .load or .html like methods (that's what I undertand reading your comments) you will have to include your conection in that page. But agree with Nico, if you want concrete help, please provide your sample code.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I had a wrong impression. I did not include page1.php to my index.php. I have an input textbox (for search) in my index.php and with jquery .keyup() I load the results in a div in index.php. In page1.php I use DB::query() but I had include db_conect.php to index.php. I think the only way is to include db_connect.php to page1.php too. The problem is if I have too many files to include, I must include them to all pages.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to `include_once('db_connect.php');` or even `require_once('db_connect.php');` in any file that you are including that will need to make a database connection. Using these methods the file will not be loaded again if already included with another file. 
`include_once()` and `require_once()` act about the same, but they handle errors differently. You can find a good explanation of that here: [Difference between require, include, require_once and include_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-require-once-and-include-once)