# Add Header, Footer and navbar files on multiple pages

Tags: php, html

Let says below are my web directories:

[image: My web distribution]

From web searching i get to use `include` or `require_once` and something similar.But I'm confuse in different directory **causes much of directory error**.

And my question is, how to **include Navbar or Footer or Specific Pages** in different directory.

Condition: Same directory as above;

Comment: `include("path/to/your/file/navbar.php")`

Comment: @WaisKamal So it means to put my 'navbar.php' into the base directory right?

Answer (score 1):

For header,navBar and footer you should used simple

```
include(page/header.php);
```

About `require` and `include` function [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-require-once-and-include-once)

> The require() function is identical to include(), except that it
>   handles errors differently. If an error occurs, the include() function
>   generates a warning, but the script will continue execution. The
>   require() generates a fatal error, and the script will stop.

But for image,css files and other js files you should follow these steps

Create `config.php` file

add this in `config.php`

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://your_website_url');//OR define('BASE_URL', 'localhost')
```

you can use this path like

```
<?php
    include('config.php');//add this code into top of the page
?>
```

and finally you can used where you want, like

For Style sheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/css/styles.css" />
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. But if I have multiple pages in ** \localhost\page\ ** and my `index.php` is in the base? How do the `include` works now?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `config.php` file in your home directory.

```
<?php
    /* Saves the directory path to base directory as `BASE_DIR`
       Example: /var/user1/home/public_html/
       'Base directory' is where your homepage/index.php is located */

       define('BASE_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
?>
```

now just require this `config.php` file

```
<?php
    require_once('config.php'); //add this line at top of your pages
    // No need to include this inside 'header.php' and 'footer.php'
?>
```

Now u can include files easily, use it in index.php as follows:

```
<?php
    require_once('config.php');

    require(BASE_DIR . 'query/conn.php');
    // becomes '/var/user1/home/public_html/query/conn.php'

    include(BASE_DIR . 'pages/header.php');
    include(BASE_DIR . 'pages/navbar.php');
    include(BASE_DIR . 'pages/footer.php');
?>
```

Note: Similar approach is used by WordPress ([learn more](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_a_WordPress_Network#If_You_just_installed_your_network))

Comment: Emm... sorry for I'm not so understanding of the use of `config.php` file from your answer above. Do you mind to explain more ?

Comment: `config.php` should be the file that contains all configuration variable like database details extras, it should also `include` or `require` all the essential files like `conn.php` as you'll most likely import it on more than one page, so its easier to edit just `config.php` than to change the `include` in every single file that uses it, in case you don't need to include `conn.php` anymore

Comment: I see, but the `navbar.php`, `index.php`, and `other.php` are dispersion into different folders. It means it still won't work fine right?

Comment: Nope, it'll work all right, just change the location to where the files are (realtive to `config.php`)

Comment: So it means if the `config.php` is place with the `aaa/bbb/ccc.php` same folder than it will works?!

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment

Comment: I mean I put the `config.php` file with the `navbar.php`, `footer.php` in the same folder than it will work without directory error right ?

Comment: You should put the config file in the root of your project

Comment: But how about the other file such as `navbar.php`, `footer.php` ?

Comment: You should check out `include()` [Php Manual]( http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), `include` n `require` does not need all files to be in same folder. I think you r not familiar with how it works. Checkout the linked documentation. Also checkout the last code snippet in my answer to see how `include` or `require` files from different locations