# What the different between PHP include or require classes and raw written classes?

Tags: php, class, oop

I have written two class at two different file, for example file `classA.php` and `classB.php`, the file written below.

file `classA.php`

```
 class a {
      public function __construct() {
           require_once('classB.php');
           $classB = new b();
      }
 }
 $classA = new a();
```

file `classB.php`

```
 class b {
      public function __construct() {
          echo "Hello World!";
      }
 }
```

And the code work fine, and output `Hello World!` as well. **But** when I write both of the class like this

```
 class a {
     public function __construct() {
         class b {
             public function __construct() {
                 echo "Hello World!";
             }
         }

         $classB = new b();
     }
 }
 $classA = new a();
```

It showing an error

> Fatal error: Class declarations may not be nested

**Which** i think both of them should be do the same thing, yesterday i found something about "arbitrary places" but i don't find the correct answer for what it is.

I just want to know why both of them, showing different result? or maybe something about `include` or `require` that i didn't know?

**NOTE**

I'm not asking what the different between `require()` and `include()` functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between require, include, require\_once and include\_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-require-once-and-include-once)

Comment: i mean the different between (included or required classes) and (raw written classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is in [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, ***all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope***.

So, unlike for variables, it doesn't matter where the `require_once` line is: the class will always be at the global scope.

Note that even the namespace of the *including* file is not applied to the *included* file, so the included functions and classes are not just in the global scope but also the root namespace.

Comment: So even when the `require_once` line inside the class a definition, the class b will be declared outside class a definition, and have a global scope?

Comment: Yes, no matter where the file is included. But only for functions and classes, not variables or constants.

Comment: This definetly answer my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to define a class within the definition of another class (unless using the new anonymous class features I'm guessing).

You can define multiple classes within the same file but not one class within the code of another class.

If using Composer to generate classmap based autoloading it will correctly work with multiple classes defined in 1 file.

Comment: you mean, using `spl_autoload("className")` right? i just want to know the reason, why the fatal-error said `class declarations may not be nested`.

Comment: why the fatal-error said class declarations may not be nested.... Because in your code example you are nesting the definition of class b inside the definition of class a.

Comment: isn't using `require()` or `include()` equal to defining the class b inside the definition of class a too?

Answer (score -1):

```
class a {
    public function __construct() {
         require_once('classB.php');
         $classB = new b();
    }
}
$classA = new a();
```

Is not same as

```
class a {
    public function __construct() {
        class b {
            public function __construct() {
                echo "Hello World!";
            }
        }

        $classB = new b();
    }
}
```

This willl also work:

```
require_once('classB.php');
class a {
    public function __construct() {         
         $classB = new b();
    }
}
$classA = new a();
```

if you use `include()` or `require()`. That means You can use their properties like variable,methos,etc.

Example: You have `vars.php` file

```
<?php
$color='red';
$car='BMW';
?>
```

THen You can use `$color` and `$car` in html like this :

```
<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
  <?php include 'vars.php';
     echo "I have a $color $car.";
  ?>
```

class is something like properties. You can use by creating instance of that.
You will get more idea from [source](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

Comment: i know, the code that you suggest is working totally fine, i have tried that earlier, but that wasn't answer my question

Comment: i don't understand, if it was only variable, i can declared it freely inside class a definition, the question is why the class didn't :v