# how can I display records from a table with a where clause

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, where-clause, record

1. Im trying to display a record with a where clause
2. It has an error "Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object"

   ```
   '<?php'
   'require_once "connect.php";'
   '$sql = "SELECT No,TimeIssued,Type FROM QueueR WHERE Type='Regular'";'
   '$result = $conn->query($sql);' 
   'if($result->num_rows > 0){'
   'echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";'
   'echo "<thead>";'
   'echo "<tr>";'
   'echo "<th>No</th>";'
   'echo "<th>TimeIssued</th>";'
   'echo "</tr>";'
   'echo "</thead>";'
   'echo "<tbody>";'
   'while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){'
   'echo "<tr>";'
   'echo "<td>" . $row['No'] . "</td>";'
   'echo "<td>" . $row['TimeIssued'] . "</td>";'
   'echo "</tr>";'
   '}'
   'echo "</tbody>";'                            
   'echo "</table>";'
   '$result->free();'
   '} else{'
   'echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";'
   '}'
   '?>'
   ```

   '''

Comment: the table should display all records where type is "Regular"

Comment: $result is not an object, Check the value of $result after calling query()

Comment: what is in your connect.php?

Comment: the error is : Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\queue\carmen\display.php on line 44

Comment: line 44 is if($result->num_rows > 0){

Comment: @MelvynMarigny Il try to check the value of $result. Thanks

Comment: @Ibrahim my connect.php is ok.. i am sure with this. Thanks

Comment: What are all those apostrophes doing?

Comment: its not part of the code. sorry. just omit the apostrophes @Strawberry

Comment: And note that, while not reserved, `no` is a recognised keyword in MySQL

Comment: The thing is it is either $conn is not connecting right or the query itself have an issue. Try testing the query a mysql client if fine use include("connect.php") instead of require_once "connect.php".

Comment: @MelvynMarigny can you show me how do I check the value of $result after the calling query

Comment: Edit your question accordingly

Comment: @Ibrahim you did it ibrahim... thanks so much

Comment: You are more than welcomed. And feel free to ask me any time. I'll Add my answer so please up-vote it and mark it as a solution.

Comment: thanks so much @melvynmarigny

Comment: thanks so much @strawberry

Comment: keep safe everyone

Comment: how do I up-vote it @Ibrahim

Comment: click the up arrow near my comment that helped you fix the issue or just click the up arrow button to the answer I just added below.

Comment: @ibrahim why was it wrong to use require_once?

Comment: Check this for detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-require-once-and-include-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `$conn` in the connect.php is connecting fine.

Try testing the query in a mysql client.

Use `include("connect.php")` instead of `require_once "connect.php"`.

Comment: can i contact you again if i have riddles to solve? thanks friend.

Comment: Sure bro, anytime.

Comment: Hi Ibrahim... I want to count all the records with type = 'regular'. I have this code but it lacks the query: $sql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM ViewQueue WHERE Type = 'Regular'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        echo [$result];

Comment: For the query use this :$sql="SELECT COUNT([PrimayKey]) FROM ViewQueue WHERE Type = 'Regular'". And $result is an array use print_r($result) or $result['name of value you want'].