# why require_once in php doesnt work in terms of preventing the duplication of the code?

Tags: php

```
<?php require_once 'includes/header.php';?>
<?php require 'includes/header.php';?>
```

Shouldn't the keyword 'require_once' stop the webpage from including the header twice? The relative file path should be no issue as the header.php can be found and displayed nav list accordingly. I've tried putting parenthesis but it doesnt work either.

Below is what the result of the code looks like

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add your code to illustrate your issue?

Comment: Yes it should prevent that. Can you provide a [mre] of the specific issue / error you're experiencing right now? Otherwise there's not much we can say to you. See also [ask]. Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason for mixing require_once and require?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between require, include, require\_once and include\_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/difference-between-require-include-require-once-and-include-once)

Comment: Out of interest...why did you add two lines for loading the header in the first place??

Comment: ooh ok, seems like require_once only prevents duplication in certain order such as <br/>
--'require_once' then 'require_once'<br/>
--'require' then 'require_once'<br/>
--'include' then 'require_once'<br/>

but not<br/>
--'require_once' then 'require'<br/>
--'require_once' then 'include'<br/>

Comment: Yeah it only prevents including the code if it's already been loaded previously. It cannot do anything about the code which comes afterwards, because it doesn't know what's going to happen in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require_once` runs the file *if it hasn't been run yet*.

`require` *always* runs the file.

You've got an odd case where the order of your lines matter. If you do this:

```php
<?php require_once 'includes/header.php';?>
<?php require 'includes/header.php';?>
```

The first line is encountered, but `header.php` hasn't been run yet, so it gets run. Then the second line is encountered, and `header.php` is always run, now for a second time.

If you change the order of the lines:

```php
<?php require 'includes/header.php';?>
<?php require_once 'includes/header.php';?>
```

The first line will be encountered, and `header.php` will be run. Then the second line will be encountered, but `header.php` has already been run, so it will be skipped.

Usually, you'll simply use `require_once` everywhere, and then you don't have to worry about order:

```php
<?php require_once 'includes/header.php';?>
<?php require_once 'includes/header.php';?>
```